# Bash sum of array

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, sum

I'm writing script in Bash and I have a problem with sum elements of array. I add to array results of `df` for two paths. In result I want to get sum elements of array.

```
use=()
i=0
for d in '$PATH1' '$PATH2'
do 
    usagebck=$(du $d | awk '{print awk $1}')
    use[i]=$usagebck
    sum=0
    for j in $use
    do
             sum=$($sum + ${use[$i]})

    done

    i=$((i+1))

done
echo ${use[*]}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Variables do not expand in single quotes. So `'$PATH'` is the literal string `$PATH`.

Comment: There's also no reason to have the `usagebck` variable in this script as-written. And `$use` will only give you the first value in the array.

Comment: So how should be $use ? $use[*] ?

Comment: Do you actually have a directory name `$PATH1`, or do you not understand the difference between single quotes and double quotes?  You probably meant to write `for d in "$PATH1" "$PATH2"`

Answer (score 3):

If your `du` has option `-s`:

```
use=()
sum=0
for d in "$PATH1" "$PATH2"
do
  usagebck="$(du -s "$d" | awk 'END{print $1}')"
  use+=($usagebck)
  ((sum+=$usagebck))
done
echo ${use[*]}
echo $sum
```

Comment: There's no reason to prefer `${use[*]}` over `"${use[@]}"` here.

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look at the parameters in [du](http://man.cx/du). On BSD based systems, there's `-c` which will give you a grand total. On GNU and BSD, there's the `-a` parameter which will report on all files for a directory.

Since you're already using `awk`, why not do everything in `awk`?

```
$ du -ms $PATH1 $PATH2 | 
  awk 'BEGIN {sum = 0} 
       END {print "Total: " sum } 
       {
           sum+=$1
           print $0
       }'
```

- `du -ms` specifies that I want the total sums of each file specified
- `BEGIN` is executed before the main `awk` program. Here I'm initializing `sum`. This isn't necessary because variables are assumed to equal zero when created.
- `END` is executed after the main `awk` program. Here, I'm specifying that I want `sum` printed.
- Between the `{ ... }` is the main Awk program. Two lines. The first line adds Column 1 (the size of the file) to `sum`. The second line prints out the entire line.